# UICollectionView - cell's background color on iOS 6

Tags: ios, ios6, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a problem with setting background color for `UICollectionViewCell` and `UICollectionReusableView` objects. It's working without a problem on iOS 7, but on iOS 6 all I'm getting is white background.

In my `UICollectionView`'s data source, I'm setting the background color in this method:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

This code works for iOS 7 only:

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

This is what I've already tried to make it works on iOS 6:

```
UIColor *backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
cell.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
cell.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.bounds];
cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
cell.layer.backgroundColor = [backgroundColor CGColor];
cell.backgroundView.layer.backgroundColor = [backgroundColor CGColor];
cell.contentView.layer.backgroundColor = [backgroundColor CGColor];
```

Unfortunately, without a success. I'm confused, and really don't know what I'm missing here.

Apart of that issue, everything else is working as expected, my `UICollectionView` displays the cells correctly on iOS 7 as well as iOS 6.

The code I am using is available on GitHub, as a part of library I've made. If you need more information about my implementation, check it here: [DRCollectionViewTableLayout-iOS](https://github.com/darrarski/DRCollectionViewTableLayout-iOS). The repository contains demo project with UICollectionView. On iOS 7 cells have random colors, on iOS 6 all cells have white backgrounds.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

**UPDATE**

or

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Comment: As far as I know this is exactly the same as `cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];` but will give it a try.

Comment: Nope. This doesn't change anything, still white backgrounds on iOS 6.

Comment: The code I am using to set background color is implemented in `UICollectionView`'s data source. `self` in that context is not a `UICollectionViewCell`, but my view controller (or something else that implements `UICollectionViewDataSource` protocol). That's not an answer.

Comment: And please, read my post again, as I wrote that I have already tried to set backgroundColor on a cell object and cell's contentView property as well.

Comment: Did you try to change the color direct to the content view, and not over the layer? Like in my updated answer.

Comment: Yes. As stated in my question - `cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];` works only on iOS 7, on iOS 6 with this code I'm getting white background. If you have a little more time, you can download demo project from my repository (link in the post) and try yourself by running the app on iOS 6 Simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. It was totally my mistake. Every cell and supplementary view in my `UICollectionView` has a `UILabel`, that fills its frame. On iOS 7 `UILabel`s have clear background color by default, but on iOS 6, the default background color is white. So, I was able to set the background color correctly on iOS 6 with this method:

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

But because there was a `UILabel` with white background on top of the cell, the cell's background color was not visible. Stupid mistake, but I think it's good to remember that when you create new `UILabel` programmatically, on iOS 7 it will have clear background, but on iOS 6 it will be white background.